# Maintaining object size while zooming in fabric js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, scaling

Is there any solution for maintaining object size even if the user zoom in or out? I want to achieve like on the google maps behavior. So if I have an object (group of object) with a height and width of 20 even if I zoom into it, it should still be 20 pixels by default. Right now the behavior I have is that when the user zoom in or out the image gets bigger / smaller. I also did looping all the objects that I have on the canvas then set the scaleX and scaleY for it but the result was so laggy for me.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c') ;

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 100
});


var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
   fill: 'red', left: 200, top: 200
});
canvas.add(circle, triangle) ;
//canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.getCenter().left, canvas.getCenter().top,1)) ;

$(function(){
   
    $('#zoomIn').click(function(){
        canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1 ) ;
    }) ;
    
    $('#zoomOut').click(function(){
        canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() / 1.1 ) ;
    }) ;
    
}) ;
```

```css
#canvasContainer {border: dotted gray thin ;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="zoomIn">+</button>
<button id="zoomOut">-</button>
<div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to maintain the scale of the objects then what is the use of canvas zoom?

Comment: I did some work around on it using the zoom level divided by 1 but the output for me was so laggy.

Comment: I already updated the fiddle example. Right now I'm experiencing so much lag when zoom in or out since the group are composed of 6 different type of objects.

Comment: The right example for my problem is the google maps. I want the object not to get bigger or smaller even if I zoom in or out into it.

Comment: Mark the lag can come from the fabric 1.5 version. Depending how much code you wrote and on what project you are, try to switch to 2.0 or at least 1.7.22  How many groups of 6 objects do you have on your map?

Comment: I'm using 1.7.22 version of fabric js. I have 9 groups that compose of 6 objects on each group from my canvas.

Comment: Should not be slow at all with 54 objects. Should be completely fine also with your approach.

Comment: This is the logic that I did for it. Maybe you suggest on how I can improve it. First I get all the canvas objects then I loop all of it. After that I set the scaleX and Y. Is that the right approach?

Comment: well is not a bad approach. nothing that should make it go slow. You are invalidating all caches every zoom, but that would happen anyway.

Comment: I refactored the objects of my Pin. Instead of making them using 6 objects as a group I used the image with borders then the object inside was the icon and circle with a text inside. Now the lag is not noticeable at all. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a built in feature of fabricjs and you have to solve it with subclassing or modification of the standard code of the fabric.Object class.

I will make an example then you can use it to find the solution that better suits your project.

So for the whole canvas there is a zoom stage, and then every object has its own transformation. This happen in `fabric.Object.prototype.transform`. At that point the zoom is done and you can't really avoid it. What you can do is zoom in the opposite direction before drawing.

So flag the objects you need to do not zoom with a new property `ignoreZoom` default to false.

Modify the fabric.Object.prototype.transform in this way:

```
transform: function(ctx, fromLeft) {
      if (this.group && !this.group._transformDone && this.group === this.canvas._activeGroup) {
        this.group.transform(ctx);
      }
      // ADDED CODE FOR THE ANSWER
      if (this.ignoreZoom && !this.group && this.canvas) {
        var zoom = 1 / this.canvas.getZoom();
        ctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
      }
      // END OF ADDED CODE FOR THE ANSWER
      var center = fromLeft ? this._getLeftTopCoords() : this.getCenterPoint();
      ctx.translate(center.x, center.y);
      this.angle && ctx.rotate(degreesToRadians(this.angle));
      ctx.scale(
        this.scaleX * (this.flipX ? -1 : 1),
        this.scaleY * (this.flipY ? -1 : 1)
      );
      this.skewX && ctx.transform(1, 0, Math.tan(degreesToRadians(this.skewX)), 1, 0, 0);
      this.skewY && ctx.transform(1, Math.tan(degreesToRadians(this.skewY)), 0, 1, 0, 0);
    },
```

This solves rendering, but does not solve controls and caching.
Caching is harder to understand, so i suggest you just disable caching for the objects that do not need to zoom.

For controls i ll be back later, is not super simple.

```js
fabric.Object.prototype.ignoreZoom = false;
fabric.Object.prototype.transform = function(ctx, fromLeft) {
          if (this.group && !this.group._transformDone && this.group === this.canvas._activeGroup) {
            this.group.transform(ctx);
          }
          // ADDED CODE FOR THE ANSWER
          if (this.ignoreZoom && !this.group && this.canvas) {
            var zoom = 1 / this.canvas.getZoom();
            ctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
          }
          // END OF ADDED CODE FOR THE ANSWER
          var center = fromLeft ? this._getLeftTopCoords() : this.getCenterPoint();
          ctx.translate(center.x, center.y);
          this.angle && ctx.rotate(degreesToRadians(this.angle));
          ctx.scale(
            this.scaleX * (this.flipX ? -1 : 1),
            this.scaleY * (this.flipY ? -1 : 1)
          );
          this.skewX && ctx.transform(1, 0, Math.tan(degreesToRadians(this.skewX)), 1, 0, 0);
          this.skewY && ctx.transform(1, Math.tan(degreesToRadians(this.skewY)), 0, 1, 0, 0);
        };

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c') ;

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 100, ignoreZoom: true
});


var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
   fill: 'red', left: 200, top: 200
});
canvas.add(circle, triangle) ;
//canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.getCenter().left, canvas.getCenter().top,1)) ;

$(function(){
   
    $('#zoomIn').click(function(){
        canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1 ) ;
    }) ;
    
    $('#zoomOut').click(function(){
        canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() / 1.1 ) ;
    }) ;
    
}) ;
```

```css
#canvasContainer {border: dotted gray thin ;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="zoomIn">+</button>
<button id="zoomOut">-</button>
<div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Andrea , thank you for your answer . I should say there is some bluring on circle in your example , and this blur becomes very strong on zooming . Is it possible to avoid it ?

Comment: what blurry issue?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Hello Andrea I've just open a post related to this question can you have a look at it please. [The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600148/keeping-same-object-size-while-zooming-with-same-left-origin-in-fabricjs). many thnks in advance

Comment: I tried fix the controls issue here but still have problem with maintaining the position https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67603796/maintaining-object-size-and-position-while-zooming-in-fabric-js

Answer (score 1):

Here are the following steps on how we solved this problem:

1.GET the scale - (1 / zoomLevel). I set it to "1" by default.

Loop all the group objects and set the "scaleX" and "scaleY" into this kind of calculation.

```
objects.forEach(object => {
  object.scaleX = (scale || 1) * 2.5;
  object.scaleY = (scale || 1) * 2.5;
});
```

Comment: if possible can you please clarify this?